# Shiny Dashboard "Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax)" when using table() function

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to draw a fairly simple plot on a shiny dashboard, however I get this error:

```
 Warnung: Error in unique.default: unique() kann nur auf Vektoren angewendet werden
  51: unique.default
  49: factor
  48: table
  47: server [C:/.../Dashboard.R#38]
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() kann nur auf Vektoren angewendet werden
```

My code looks like this (barely any different from the hello world example):

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# my libraries #
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(),
  
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 400)),
    
    box(title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Years:", 1970, 2017, 2000))
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- read.csv("filename.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8", fill = TRUE)
  
  dat <-
    reactive({
      dat %>%
        filter(year > input$slider) %>%
        select(year)
    })
  
  tab <- table(dat)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(
      tab,
      main = "My Main Title",
      ylab = "Amount",
      xlab = "Year",
      type = "o"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error has to be in my use of the `table()` function (since that is in line `#38` in the original code), but the error message is too unspecific for me to find out what's wrong ...

Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dat` object is a reactive, so try calling `tab <- table(dat())` instead. Also, place the reactive call within a render function, like so:

```
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    tab <- table(dat())
    plot(
      tab,
      main = "My Main Title",
      ylab = "Amount",
      xlab = "Year",
      type = "o"
    )
  })
```

I'd also avoid reusing variable names as a general coding practice.

Comment: Now I get the following error:

    `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
    Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: You have to place reactive evaluations within render functions

Comment: Oh, makes sense. That fixed it. Thank you very much!